# My code is not loading the textarea from tinymce.min.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My code is not loading the textarea from tinymce.min.js , i have included everything and i have also tried DTEDITOR don't remember the name but still no solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Admin Area    </title>
        <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});    
        </script>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="grey">
    <form method="post" action="insert_product.php" enctype="multipart/form-  data">
    <table width="700" align="center" border="1" bgcolor="#006699">
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2">     
                <h2> Insert new Product</h2>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">   
                <b>Product Title</b>    
            </td>
            <td>     
                <input type="text" name="product_title" size="50"/>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">    
                <b>Product Category</b>    
            </td>
            <td>     
                <select name="product_cart">
                    <option>Select a Category</option>
                    <?php
                        $get_brands="select * from brands";
                        $run_brands=mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);
                        while($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array( $run_brands)){
                            $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
                            $brand_title=$row_brands['brand_title'];            
                            echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title </option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">    
                <b>Product image 1</b>    
            </td>
            <td>     
                <input type="file" name="product_img1"/>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <b>Product image 2</b>    
            </td>
            <td>     
                <input type="file" name="product_img2"/>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">    
                <b>Product image 3</b>    
            </td>
            <td>     
                <input type="file" name="product_img3"/>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">    
                <b>Product price</b>    
            </td>
            <td>     
                <input type="text" name="product_price"/>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">    
                <b>Product Description</b>    
            </td>
            <td>     
                <textarea name="product_desc" cols="35" rows="10" ></textarea>     
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">    
                <b>Product Keywords</b>    
            </td>
            <td>     
                <input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="50"/>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2">     
                <input type="submit" name="submit"/>     
            </td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</htmal>
```

Comment: Try Firefox + Firebug to check what is going wrong. Or IE press F12, or Opera DragonFly.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: shouldn't cause issue with your `<textarea>`, but you never close your `<select name="product_cart">` (missing `</select>`)

Comment: Any chance you have other javascript in the page that might have caused the issue? The tinymce bit seems just fine.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes their was , i checked the source of the tinymce the console was showing error on that However i downloaded the older version of it and place it in the folder but still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});` before the HTML for the `textarea` element exists.  This script is run inline with the page loading, so you'll have to either move the script somewhere after the `textarea` element, or create an `onload` event handler.